# How to change language folder on the same page? (by using jQuery or JavaScript)

Tags: jquery, path, directory, switch-statement

I have a site with 2 languages that are `En` and `Th`. Each language has the same file name in different folder, i.e. `/en/` and `/th/`. I've created `<a>` tag to switch between these 2 languages on my included header file (asp).

The question is how to get the current path wherever you are, and change folder name to `en` or `th`? (If you are inside English Contact page, clicking `th` will take you to Thai Contact page.)

I have tried to create a function:

```
<script>
     function changeLanguage(to) {
         var from = jQuery.url.segment(-2);
         var url = from.replace('/' + from + '/', to);
         document.location = url;
     }
</script>
```

to use in `<a>` tag.

```
<a id="flags" href="#" onclick="changeLanguage(en)"> English </a>|<a href="#" onclick="changeLanguage(th)" >Thai</a>
```

But it does not work. I've spent so many days to find a similar question. I found some but still couldn't apply to my code. So please help me. I'm really newbie on this and really need your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wouldn't the `var url = from.replace('/' + from + '/', to);` statement  change your **www.domain.com/en/** to **www.domain.comth** ? Is produced url correct?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a string, at the moment you are saying changeLanguage(variable named en), use:

```
onclick="changeLanguage('en')"
```

or use jquery to bind the click event for you:

```
<a id="flags" href="#en" class="flag"> English </a>|<a href="#th" class="flag">Thai</a>
```

and use the jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".flag").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var to = $(this).attr("href").substring(1); //removes the hash value # (#en will become 'en')
        var from = jQuery.url.segment(-2);
        var url = from.replace('/' + from + '/', '/' + to + '/');
        document.location = url;
    });
});
```

I have moved the language text to the href instead so we can catch that in the click event.

an example that will pop an alert to what language you clicked on: http://jsbin.com/epavoh/2/

Comment: I think need to add `return false;` inside the `click()`, if it gets triggered by a hyperlink.

Comment: No, you dont have to add `return false;` Im using the `event.preventDefault` http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ that works in my meaning better.

Comment: Oh, right right. though, my logic says that `preventDefault()` as a function is slower then `return false`.

Answer (score 0):

@voigtan, I've spent time try to understand your code. But no matter i've tried, this code still add #en or #th after my URL.

```
    <script>
     $(".flag").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var to = this.href.substring(1); 
     var from = jQuery.url.segment(-2);
     var url = from.replace('/' + from + '/', '/' + to + '/');
     document.location = url;   
     });        
    </script>
```

with

```
   <a id="flags" href="#en" class="flag"> English </a>|<a href="#th" class="flag">Thai</a>
```

Yes, I know what  jQuery.url.segment(-2) use for. It will find the segment of URL from 2 path from the right, right? my folder was root/en/default.asp, so (-2) will return the value of "en" or "th".

Actually, no need to be Javascript or jQuery. Any thing would be ok just can fit my .asp, that's all.